# Is Loosely Coupled on MVVM even posible?

Tags: c#, mvvm

I'm currently working on my first MVVM application using Caliburn.Micro. If understand correctly the concept of Loosely Coupled, I must be able to extract every class of my project, isolated it on a blank solution, and it must compile without problems because there is no direct reference to others classes, right?

**So my question is this:**

Where is the place to create the viewmodels for distinct views and mantain the loosely coupled model?

I ask this because many examples on the web do something like this:

```
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive {  
int count = 1;  

public void OpenTab() {  
    ActivateItem(new TabViewModel {  
        DisplayName = "Tab " + count++  
    });  
}  
}
```

Where TabViewModel is the viewmodel for the desired view. But here, shellviewmodel is tightly coupled to TabViewModel

Other option i've try is to create some sort of menu class like this:

```
class MenuItem
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Type ViewType { get; set; }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
new MenuItem(){Title="My menu",ViewType=typeof(ProductosViewModel)}
```

And use a generic creation procedure, but again this class is coupled with ProductosViewModel.

So what other options do i have? Or should i forget about strict loosely coupled?
Thank you!

Comment: How much user interaction are you expecting from the UI?  As a general rule, the more interactive your UI is, the more tightly coupled to the data it's going to be.  View Models can go a long way towards reducing this tight coupling, but ultimately you're still going to need to know *something* about the data.

Comment: Thank you Robert. From my experience in the use of an application the interaction with the UI tends to increase, so i have to tell many at least.